# Getting coordinates of a table and storing it in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created a page and it has some tables. I have made these tables draggable and now I need to store the coordinates of the table as it moved over the provided area using PHP.
please help me out in doing this, I couldn't figure it out. The code of the html page is:

```
<table class="smsSecond"><!--bgcolor="#4ab54d"><class="smsSecond"--     this is td bgcolor: bgcolor="#4ab54d"-->
        <tr style="background-color: #3C3C3C;" >
             <td colspan="2" width="auto" align="center">Ticket Info<img id="delete" src="icons/delete.png" height="10" width="10" style="float: right;"/></td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center"><!-- style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px;"-->
            <td>
                Ticket number
            </td>
            <td>
                HFK-864-69976
            </td>
        </tr>


        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center"><!--style="color: #000000; font-size: 15px; background-color: #FFFFFF" --><!--background-color: #A4EAF6-->
            <td>
                Department
            </td>
            <td>
                Support
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Priority
            </td>
            <td>
                P3-Normal
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Open Date and Time
            </td>
            <td>
                2011-02-28 21:24:01          
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Close Date and Time
            </td>
            <td>
                2011-02-28 21:24:01
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Total Time
            </td>
            <td>
                00:03:09
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Ticket Spent
            </td>
            <td>
                00:02:00
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                No. of staff worked
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Ticket Status
            </td>
            <td>
                Closed
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                SLA
            </td>
            <td>
                Yes
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Type
            </td>
            <td>
                Issue
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Red Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Yellow Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr class="evenrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Orange Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr class="oddrow" align="center">
            <td>
                Closed by
            </td>
            <td>
                Harsha p
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

the jquery used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".smsSecond").draggable({containment: ".maincol"});//, revert: true

    $(".smsSecond").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(500);
    });

    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {

    $('.smsSecond').show(500);

    return false;

    });


});
    </script>
```

Comment: why you are using two jQuery libs and two jQuery-ui libs?

Comment: That's lot of code ! Are you looking for Ajax... ?

Comment: Don't bother about the code. I just need to store the coordinates of any of the tables with <table class="smsSecond">.
javascript, ajax, anything would work